# wkhtmltopdf command fails in Meteor app

Tags: meteor, wkhtmltopdf

I'm working on a Meteor app. And, in a section of the app, there is requirement to render a html page into pdf file.

`wkhtmltopdf` is install properly in my local machine with linux distribution (i.e. Ubuntu 16.04), and pdf are also generated if I execute following command:

```
  wkhtmltopdf https://google.com google.pdf
```

In Meteor app, certain html template file is to be converted into pdf, and the logic is written as follows:

```
  wkhtmltopdf --dpi 300 --margin-top ...
```

But when the action is carried out for conversion in the back-end logic, following error occurs:

```
  Error: Command failed: wkhtmltopdf --dpi 300 --margin-top 0 --margin-right 0  --margin-bottom 0  --margin-left 0   /tmp/118330-6025-bh2dza.0pcwa.html /tmp/118330-6025-ou28zs.pz78.pdf
```

In my local envrionment path for `wkhtmltopdf` is set properly, and works fine. But, for the Meteor app the command fails.

Any help/suggestion?

Comment: How you do trigger the command from the client to the backend and from backend to the cmd? Does the node process that executes the command has permissions to read and write files in the `/tmp` folder? Maybe you try using another folder than `/tmp`?

Comment: Since I've used `/tmp/118330-6025-bh2dza.0pcwa.html /tmp/118330-6025-ou28zs.pz78.pdf` as the source and output respectively, the access is denied for the folder `/tem/...`. So, while running the meteor server, the access to the server must be provided.